# Why Does Math.pow(x,y) Count as a Double?

Tags: java, int, double, pow

I'm writing a Java program to calculate how much food it will take to get a monster to a certain level in My Singing Monsters. When I run the program, it says, "cannot convert from double to int". Can someone explain why this is? Here's the program.

```
int totalFood = 0;
int level = 1;
int levelMeal = 5*(Math.pow(2,level-1));
int mealNumber = 1;
int levelGoal = 1;
while(level != levelGoal)
{
  if(mealNumber != 5)
  {
    mealNumber += 1;
    totalFood += levelMeal;
  }
  else if(mealNumber == 5)
  {
    mealNumber = 0;
    level += 1;
  }
}
if(level == levelGoal)
{
  println("The total amount of food required for a monster to reach level " + levelGoal + " is " + totalFood + " food.");
}
```

Comment: [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)) the javadoc.

Comment: When the error is displayed, the line that says "int levelMeal = 5*(Math.pow(2,level-1));" is highlighted.

Comment: @JasonChen What datatype pow returns? And to what type of value are you trying to assign it? When you'll answer those questions, the answer will be obvious.

Comment: Should I convert the levelMeal to a double?

Comment: The error really does speak for itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll have to do this:

```
int levelMeal = (int) (5*(Math.pow(2,level-1)));
                  ^
           this is a cast
```

As you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29), `Math.pow()` returns a `double` by design, but if you need an `int` then an explicit cast must be performed.

Comment: `5<<(level-1)` would be a more appropriate implementation (if you fix the same overflow problems you get from going through double), and will be more precise for very high `level`s (if you'd use `long` or even a bignum type instead of `int`).

Comment: @Rhymoid - That's what I put in my answer. However, I overlooked the fact that I could just directly shift the 5 instead of doing a multiply afterwards. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think there's typically hardware support on most modern processors for doing floating-point powers, but not integers. Because of that, for a *general* power, it's actually faster to do `Math.power` with a `double` and then convert it back to an `int`.

However, in this case there's a faster way to do it for ints. Since you're doing a power of 2, you can just use the [bitwise left-shift operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) instead:

```
int levelMeal = 5*(1<<(level-1));
```

As Rhymoid pointed out in his comment, that expression can be further simplified to remove the `1`:

```
int levelMeal = 5<<(level-1);
```

Comment: Just `5<<(level-1)` will do too. I doubt javac is clever enough to make that optimization by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Math.pow return double and you assigning double value to int this is why it is giving error. You have to downcast it. Like

```
int levelMeal = (int)5*(Math.pow(2,level-1));
```