# why java Math.pow arguments double?

Tags: java, api, floating-point

why Math.pow API in java is with double arguments, what is the rationale or use of writing with double ?

As caluclating the floats and double involve precision, round off errors etc.. are involved why not there is no separate API to caluclate with integers ?

Why there is no separate method

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071363/calculating-powers-in-java, it might answer both of your concerns.

Comment: The results of power computations are often irrational numbers that can only be approximated, and double provides the closest approximations with fast compact arithmetic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Does Math.pow(x,y) Count as a Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326902/why-does-math-powx-y-count-as-a-double)

Comment: Math.pow has also many corner cases one should be aware of: https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/03/16/java-math-pow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of pow are often irrational, fractional or too large to store as a `long`, If you want to use powers of integers you can use

```
 BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(100);
 BigInteger bi2 = bi.pow(20); // 10^40
```

Another reason maybe that Math has many function which are taken from C, and also from common CPU instructions sets.  C only has a floating point method and x64 only has the floating point version of pow.

Comment: When is an integer to the power of another integer ever irrational?  *Fractional* results (i.e., for negative exponents) *are* an issue, though.